# How to add new key-value to existing array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array, keyvaluepair

I have a form in PHP that takes in two values: `server_id` and `user_id` (which can be more than one separated by `','`). I retrieve some data from a table and stored them as array. Using the same `server_id` and `user_id`, I would like to retrieve additional from another table but store them into the same array.

This is what I have so far.

```
//Data from PHP form stored in array
$inputData = Array ( [server_id] => 10 
                        [user_id] => Array ( [0] => 111[1] => 222) ) 

//Existing array storing data retrieved from persons table
$userData = 
Array 
( 
    [0] => Array 
        (

            [user_id] => 111
            [server_id] => 10
            [user_name] => Harry Pottter 
            [user_age] => 18 ) 

    [1] => Array 
        ( 
            [user_id] => 222 
            [server_id] => 10 
            [user_name] => Hermione
            [user_age] => 18 ) 
)

//retrieving additional data from user_contact table
$sql = "SELECT user_phone, user_address FROM user_contact 
        WHERE user_id = ? AND server_id = ?";

foreach($user_id as $user)
{
    $statement= $DB->link->prepare($sql);
    $statement->bind_param("si", $server_id, $user);
    $statement->execute();

    if($resultSet = $statement->get_result())
    {
        while($row = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
        {
            userData[$key]['user_phone'] = $row['user_phone'];
            userData[$key]['user_address'] = $row['user_address'];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so you want another query inside the foreach?

Comment: if `$key = count($userData)` (you are using a `$`, for `userData`, right), then what you have should do it, from what I see.

Comment: @Ghost - I need to query another db, with a totally different config so yes I need to loop it unless there is any other way to do this I am alright either way.

Comment: @JeremyMiller - yes there should be a $ for userData.

Comment: @Cryssie well, you could just create just one query join to pull that other info, most likely that other table is connected right?

Comment: @Ghost - unfortunately, it's not. Two different tables on two different server with different port. If it is it would make my life easier.

Answer (score 0):

try using array_push()

like

```
<?php
$stack = array("orange", "banana");
array_push($stack, "apple", "raspberry");
print_r($stack);
?>
```